What are the sabbaths in Matthew 12:1-2?
Matthew 12:1-2 (YLT)

At that time did Jesus go on the sabbaths through the corn, and his disciples were hungry, and they began to pluck ears, and to eat, and the Pharisees having seen, said to him, `Lo, thy disciples do that which it is not lawful to do on a sabbath.'
ἐν ἐκείνῳ τῷ καιρῷ ἐπορεύθη ὁ Ἰησοῦς τοῖς σάββασιν διὰ τῶν σπορίμων οἱ δὲ μαθηταὶ αὐτοῦ ἐπείνασαν καὶ ἤρξαντο τίλλειν στάχυας καὶ ἐσθίειν οἱ δὲ Φαρισαῖοι ἰδόντες εἶπαν αὐτῷ ἰδοὺ οἱ μαθηταί σου ποιοῦσιν ὃ οὐκ ἔξεστιν ποιεῖν ἐν σαββάτῳ

Matthew begins by specifying the sabbaths τοῖς σάββασιν. The Pharisees protest the disciples are doing what is not lawful on a sabbath ἐν σαββάτῳ.
What are the sabbaths in Matthew 12:1-2?

Ellicott seems baffled by this solitary reference to 'second-first' sabbath. Myself, I see it as a spiritual allusion to the first sabbath being a representation of that which was to come - the eternal rest in Christ. Thus the second is that eternal rest indeed. Which is demonstrated in that both Christ and his disciples have no problem with (in the eternal rest) plucking corn, grinding and eating it. Those who have not yet entered into rest (in Christ) feel constrained to continue the figure. Which is already fulfilled in Christ. Up-voted +1.

The Greek word "σάββατα" (sávvata) is derived from the Aramaic word "שַׁבְּתָא" (shabtá), which is used to emphatically express the sabbath. It is not plural, but singular, and may be translated "sabbath day", i.e., the day of the cessation of the work, i.e., in the sense that Jesus went through the sabbath day through the crops (the day of the cessation of the work). In contrast, the plain "sabbath", is simply translated as "cessation of work". I.e. The Pharisees said: it is not permitted on the sabbath (on the cessation of work).
Conclusion
σάββατα = day of rest from work
σάββατον = cessation of work


τοῖς σάββασιν is plural, per the plural definite article τοῖς.

@AFrazier The word has been Hellenized and thus has acquired grammatical cases. The meaning has to do with the emphasis given when it is used, and is translated as singular: shabbath day.

Luke 5:17 & 6:1-3 KJV
And it came to pass on the second sabbath after the first, that he went through the corn fields; and his disciples plucked the ears of corn, and did eat, rubbing them in their hands.
6:2 And certain of the Pharisees said unto them, Why do ye that which is not lawful to do on the sabbath days?
Luke 6:2 uses "sabbath days" vs. "sabbath day" in this portion of the gospels because of 2 events which took place on consecutive sabbath days.
Assumption: Luke 5:17 through Luke 6:5 took place over the course of at least 2 weeks of sabbaths.
The healing which took place in Luke 5:18-26, with the assumption that 5:17 is speaking of a sabbath day when the KJV uses "certain" day and the fact that Yeshua was teaching while others were sitting. Sitting was the customary position for teaching compared to standing while reading as Yeshua did in Luke 4:16-20.
The other 'violation' on a sabbath day is in Luke 6:1 where the disciples are falsely accused of violating the sabbath when plucking grain in the field.
Conclusion: If these are the 2 events the Pharisees had in mind in Luke 6:2, that may be a reason why the plural form is used in Luke 6:1 or in this case, Luke 6:2.
The stretch idea is that the rubbing of grain was a time marker for the season of the wheat harvest and the Sabbath of one of the weeks is a High Sabbath or Holy Sabbath; which occur within the week of one of the major feasts of Yahweh. That could be a little out there.

There is a curious feature of the word "sabbath" in the Greek NT: the plural is often used for the singular but never the singular for the plural.
Note the comments of Professor Francois de Blois in https://blogs.ucl.ac.uk/calendars-ancient-medieval-project/2015/07/15/the-etymology-of-sabbath/

The seventh day is designated by the Hebrew or Aramaic loan word
σάββατον (neuter singular) or σάββατα (neuter plural). Although there
are a few passages where σάββατα does in fact mean ‘two or more
Sabbaths’, in most cases both the singular and the plural forms are
used to designate a single Sabbath. In particular, in the Septuagint
we can observe that Hebrew šabbòṯ is translated either by σάββατον or
by σάββατα without any discernable difference of meaning. It seems
possible that σάββατα is in fact a borrowing of the Old Aramaic
singular noun in the determined state *šabbatā (Middle Aramaic:
šabbṯā), which Greek speakers subsequently reinterpreted as a neuter
plural and that the singular σάββατον is a back-formation.

Similarly, BDAG makes a similar comment that the singular and plural of "Sabbath" are, in many places, used interchangeably.  Again, the plural is often used for the singular but never the singular for the plural.
This is confirmed by a typical example of parallel accounts below:
Matthew 12

V1: At that time Jesus went through the grainfields on the Sabbath - PLURAL
V2: Your disciples are doing what is unlawful on the Sabbath - SINGULAR

Mark 2

V23: One Sabbath - PLURAL - Jesus was passing through the grainfields
V24: Look, why are they doing what is unlawful on the Sabbath? - PLURAL

Luke 6

V1: One Sabbath - SINGULAR - Jesus was passing through the grainfields
V2: Why are you doing what is unlawful on the Sabbath? - PLURAL

Again, it is clear that the singular and plural are used, in some situations for the singular, interchangeably.

In 12:1 rather than write the singular σαββάτῳ (Sabbath) Matthew wrote the plural σάββασιν (Sabbaths) as an idiom which he wants the reader to understand as σαββάτῳ (Sabbath). Then in verse 12:2 he did not use the idiom σάββασιν, instead he wrote σαββάτῳ?

@RevelationLad - true - look at the parallel passages that use the singular and plural almost at random.  Dozens of other examples could be quoted.  I once looked them all (68 instances) to find a pattern but could discern none.

Most translators omit the plural but the OP is correct that the Greek does say "sabbaths." The plural is apparently Matthew's way of expressing what Luke says in his version of the same event:
Luke 6:1

And it came to pass, on the second-first sabbath, as he is going
through the corn fields, that his disciples were plucking the ears,
and were eating, rubbing with the hands. (YLT)

The meaning of the second-first sabbath has been discussed previously here. Barnes explains:

{Luke} says that it was "the second Sabbath after the first." To
understand this, it is proper to remark that the "Passover" was
observed during the month "Abib," or Nisan, answering to the latter
part of March and the first of April. The feast was held seven days,
commencing on the fourteenth day of the month Exodus 12:1-28; Exodus
23:15, on the "second" day of the paschal week... This second day in the feast of the Passover, or of unleavened bread, was the beginning, therefore, from which they reckoned toward the Pentecost. The Sabbath in the week following would be the "second Sabbath" after this first one in the reckoning, and this was doubtless the time mentioned when Christ went through the fields.

Conclusion: Matthew refers to the second-first sabbath as "the sabbaths."

Your YLT version of the Bible shows how the words used in the structure of a sentence can give a whole different meaning to the text.  In the KJV, this is the way Matthew 12:1, 2 is stated:  "At that time Jesus went on the sabbath day through the corn; and his disciples were hungered, and began to pluck the ears of corn, and to eat.  But when the Pharisees saw it, they said unto him, Behold, thy disciples do that which is not lawful to do upon the sabbath day."
So, to answer your question, from the meaning of my text, the sabbath day was the 7th day of the week, and this indicates it was a single action.  The YLT version you are reading from might indicate that it was a habitual action over multiple sabbaths.
